# Angular cannot match any routes

Tags: angular, error-handling, routes

I am trying to understand how the roiuting works on Angular.
So here is my header and I want to go on different pages. 
[my simple header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3wcQ.jpg)

app.routing.ts:

```
export const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: 'auth', component: AuthComponent },
    { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent }
]

export const ROUTING: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
   ...
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
    ROUTING
  ],
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.html

```
 <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

home.component.html

```
 <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Home <--> auth is OK

Home <--> about is OK

But auth <--> about is not working

I get this kind error:

> Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'about/auth'

As we can see the url is about/auth insead of auth`enter code here`

Comment: Can you please add the code you're using to change routes, whether that be the template HTML, or ts.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you are using relative specified relative paths inside `routerLink` directive, which basically end up appending mentioned route to current route like that's why you got `about/auth` on `about` to `auth` redirection. To solve this issue use Absolute routing like below.

```
[routerLink]="'/auth'"`
[routerLink]="'/about'"`
```

The reason being is, when you have route without `/` mentioned inside the `routerLink` directive, it will eventually end up appending the route to `currentRoute` since its [relative routing](https://angular.io/guide/router#relative-navigation). Make sure you should use absolute route while navigating to particular route (add `/` before your route).

Comment: I did, I am getting this error at loading the page:Error: Invalid configuration of route '/about': path cannot start with a slash

Comment: show me your anchor tags that you used for navigation... It must have `routerLink`

Comment: I indeed added in the path... I added it in the routerlink and that worked!Thanks man. I am going to read the chapter about routing